# InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociation when creating CloudFront distribution via Terraform

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, terraform

I want to create a CloudFront distribution that could invoke a `lambda` (@edge). I was able to do that using AWS console. I am now trying to achieve the same using Terraform. My configurations are as follows.

First, I created a role for lambda.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "my_edge_lambda_iam_role" {
  name = "my_edge_lambda_iam_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Next, I created a the lambda.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "redirect_lambda" {
  filename         = "myscript.js.zip"
  function_name    = "my_js_script"
  role             = "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/my_edge_lambda_iam_role"
  handler          = "index.handler"
  runtime          = "nodejs4.3-edge"
}
```

Finally, I (attempted to) created the CloudFront distribution using the ARN of the lambda function above. The definition is as follows.

```
resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  origin {
    domain_name = "my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com"
    origin_id   = "<my S3 path>"
  }

  enabled             = true
  is_ipv6_enabled     = true

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = "<my target origin>"

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    lambda_function_association {
      event_type = "viewer-request"
      lambda_arn = "<arn of the lambda function denerated above>"
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "allow-all"
    min_ttl                = 0
    default_ttl            = 86400
    max_ttl                = 31536000
  }

  price_class = "PriceClass_All"

  viewer_certificate {
    cloudfront_default_certificate = true
 }

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }
}
```

When trying to create the distribution, I get the following exception.

```
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_cloudfront_distribution.s3_distribution: InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociation: Failed to retrieve the function from Lambda. ErrorCode: AccessDeniedException Function: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:12345678:function:my_js_script
    status code: 400, request id: 65579sd33-3f2d5-181e7-9140-79c1ff79fbdd
```

Could it be a problem with how I have defined the role?

Comment: It's not clear how this would work with Terraform, but there appears to be a requirement to tell "lambda" that "edgelambda" is allowed to fetch the function... it's a permission on the function itself (not the role) (I think) (maybe)... http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html#lambda-edge-permissions

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Is there an example Terraform config on how I can add a permission to a lambda?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121551/invalidlambdafunctionassociation-when-creating-cloudfront-distribution-via-terra#comment75266157_44121551), you need to add an [`aws_lambda_permission`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_permission.html) resource to allow an AWS service to retrieve the Lambda function.

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudfront" {
  statement_id   = "AllowExecutionFromCloudFront"
  action         = "lambda:GetFunction"
  function_name  = "${aws_lambda_function.redirect_lambda.function_name}"
  principal      = "edgelambda.amazonaws.com"
}
```

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-permissions.html#using-service-linked-roles) have a little more information about how to allow this outside of Terraform, using the CLI in this case:

```
aws lambda add-permission \               
 --function-name arn \
 --statement-id statement-id \
 --action lambda:GetFunction \
 --principal edgelambda.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating the Lambda function and publishing a version in the AWS Lambda console, you can reference the specific version of the Lambda function in your CloudFront distribution template using the lambda_arn variable.

`lambda_arn = "${aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn}:${aws_lambda_function.lambda.version}"`

aws_lambda_function.lambda.arn: This represents the ARN (Amazon Resource Name) of your Lambda function.
aws_lambda_function.lambda.version: This specifies the version of the Lambda function that you want to associate with the CloudFront distribution.
By combining these two values with a colon (:) separator, you form the complete ARN of the specific Lambda function version to be used in the CloudFront distribution template.

Make sure to replace aws_lambda_function.lambda with the actual name or resource ID of your Lambda function in your Terraform code.